# Why server does not send true file size and client download file

Tags: c#, server, tcp, network-programming

I am creating basic TCP server-client musicdownload app on c#. I came the last step download mp3 file server to client firstly sent file size after that file content in 1024 chunk size (temporary buffer) but client can not get no receive size of file always 193445465 similiar a number real size should be 805KB

client

```
     private void server1Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NetworkStream stream = server.GetStream();
            string download_song = searchBar.Text;
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("send4thisclient " + download_song);
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            searchBar.Clear();
            stream.Flush();

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                downloadMusic(download_song);
            });
        }


      private void downloadMusic(string download_song)
        {
            NetworkStream stream = server.GetStream();

            // Read the file size
            byte[] fileSizeBytes = new byte[2 * 2];
            stream.Read(fileSizeBytes, 0, fileSizeBytes.Length);
            int fileSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(fileSizeBytes, 0);


            // Read the file data
            byte[] fileData = new byte[fileSize];
            int bytesReadFileData;
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            while (totalBytesRead < fileSize && (bytesReadFileData = stream.Read(fileData, totalBytesRead, fileSize - totalBytesRead)) > 0)
            {
                totalBytesRead += bytesReadFileData;
            }

            // Save the downloaded file
            string currentFolder = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            string filePath = Path.Combine(currentFolder, download_song);
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileData);
            MessageBox.Show("downloaded");
        }
```

server

```
 if (message.StartsWith("send4thisclient"))
                {
                    string[] list = message.Split(" ");
                    string sName = list[1];
                    string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                    string file = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, sName);

                    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        // Get the file size
                        long fileSize = fileStream.Length;
                        byte[] fileSizeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileSize);
                   

                        // Send file size to client
                        stream.Write(fileSizeBytes, 0, fileSizeBytes.Length);

                        // Send file data to client in chunks
                        byte[] buffers = new byte[1024];
                        int bytesRead2;

                        while ((bytesRead2 = fileStream.Read(buffers, 0, buffers.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            stream.Write(buffers, 0, bytesRead2);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
```

figure out problem ..

Comment: You seem to have no proper framing mechanism. How does the serve know where the end of the requested filename is? And why don't you just use a higher level protocol such as HTTP rather than trying to reinvent the wheel? Also, why mess around with read/write loops, you can just do `fileStream.CopyTo(stream);` Also why aren't you doing this `async` you are going to lock up the UI?

Comment: @Charlieface file size duplicated for example server send 700kb file but in client side file double itself